# Assembly number change error

Tags: assembly, printf, nasm, x86-64, mach-o

I tried to make a assembly program that took one number, and then printed it. But when I wrote 1, it wrote 4171. Why, and how can I fix it? I am using 64 bit assembly, I assembled it with `nasm -f macho64 scanf.asm`, and I linked it with `gcc -o scanf scanf.o -Wl,-no-pie`. And I've tried to use square brackets around number in the scan macro (for a pointer to the varible number), but nasm mach-o didn't allow it, so I didn't do that.

Here is my code:

```
; lib.asm
extern _printf
extern _scanf

%macro print 2

    push rbp

    mov rdi, %1
    mov rsi, %2

    xor rax, rax

    call _printf

    pop rbp

%endmacro

%macro scan 2

    push rbp

    mov rdi, %1
    mov rsi, %2

    mov rax, 0
    call _scanf

    pop rbp

%endmacro

; scanf.asm

%INCLUDE "lib.asm"

section .bss
    number resd 1
section .text
    global _main
_main:

    print str_out, qst
    scan int_in, number

    print ans, number

exit:

    mov rax, 0x2000001
    xor rbx, rbx
    syscall

section .data
    str_out db '%s', 0xa, 0
    int_in db '%d', 0
    int_out db '%d', 0xa, 0


    qst db 'Enter a number: ', 0

    ans db 'You wrote: %d', 0xa, 0
```

Comment: Your `print ans, number` seems to be printing out the address of `number` not the number itself. What if you replace `print ans, number` with `movsx rax, dword [number]` `print ans, rax` . In this case `mov eax, [number]` `print ans, rax` should work too.

Comment: nasm prints "scanf.asm:12: error: Mach-O 64-bit format does not support 32-bit absolute addresses" when I try "movsx rax, dword [number]", and when I try "mov rax, [number]".

Comment: Okay try it this way then `mov rax, [rel number]` forcing it to use relative RIP addressing

Comment: I put 'default rel' at the top instead.

Comment: My answer suggests that as an option rather than using `rel` on each memory operand. Glad you got it going.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The macro to print the answer is incorrect.

```
print ans, number
```

When the macro is expanded you'd get:

```
push rbp

mov rdi, ans      ; RDI = Address of ans
mov rsi, number   ; RSI = Address of number

xor rax, rax

call _printf

pop rbp
```

I have commented the 2 lines above and their meaning. A format string of `'You wrote: %d'` says to print an integer. You have passed it the address of `number` instead. To resolve this get the 32-bit value from `number` and place it in an available register and pass that register to your macro.

To do this you can replace:

```
print ans, number
```

With:

```
mov eax, [rel number] ; Get the 32-bit number from number and store in eax
                      ; Using RIP relative addressing 
print ans, rax        ; Print the 32-bit word in the bottom half of RAX.
```

That would expand to:

```
push rbp

mov rdi, ans      ; RDI = Address of ans
mov rsi, rax      ; RSI = number to print in RAX

xor rax, rax

call _printf

pop rbp
```

**Note**: We use `mov eax, [rel number]` with the `rel` directive to change the default absolute address behavior to RIP relative addressing. If you wish to use `mov eax, [number]` and avoid having to specify `rel` you can override the default addressing and place `default rel` at the top of your assembly file. The default is `default abs`.

---

You may ask why I suggested:

```
mov eax, [rel number]   ; Get the 32-bit number from number and store in eax
                        ; Using RIP relative addressing 
print ans, rax          ; Print the 32-bit word in the bottom half of RAX.
```

Rather than:

```
print ans, [rel number]
```

Ultimately the macro would have attempted to do this:

```
mov rsi, [rel number]   ; Get the 64-bit number from number and store in RDI
```

You defined `number` this way:

```
number resd 1
```

This is a 32-bit value, not 64-bit. `mov rsi, [rel number]` would have attempted to move 8 bytes from the memory location `number` into *RSI*. This will likely cause no issues in your sample code but it is considered bad form. I consider it a bug despite the fact that it may work.

Comment: It worked, but I had to put 'DEFAULT REL' at the top to solve the nasm error.

Comment: I put a comment about that at the bottom of my answer, however it should have accepted `mov eax, [rel number]` without `default rel` at the top.